# Access Query and Sql Query Results Don't Match

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, vba, case

Access query:

```
IIf([rptd mean net (g)] > 0, [rptd mean net (g)] - ([Actual Tare Wt (g)] - [Machine Tare Wt (g)]), [Mean Gross (g)] - [actual tare wt (g)]) AS [Net Mean Wt (g)]
```

Here is the result i am getting from access [click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziOuT.png)

SQL query:

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN [Net Weight Tracking].[Rptd Mean Net (g)] > 0 
         THEN (([Net Weight Tracking].[Rptd Mean Net (g)]) - ([Net Weight Tracking].[Actual Tare Wt (g)])- ([Net Weight Tracking].[Machine Tare Wt (g)])) 
         ELSE ([Net Weight Tracking].[Mean Gross (g)]) - ([Net Weight Tracking].[Actual Tare Wt (g)])  
   END AS [Net Mean Wt (g)]
FROM 
   dbo.[Net Weight Tracking]
```

Here is result I am getting for SQL [click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIRsK.png)

My question is: what is causing the difference in the [Net Mean Wt (g)], is it an problem with my my SQL case statement if so how can I fix my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Access Query has parentheses that are messing it up:

```
[rptd mean net (g)]-([Actual Tare Wt (g)]-[Machine Tare Wt (g)])
```

327-(46.6-47) = 327 - (-.4) = 328.1

Your SQL query doesn't have these parentheses.

Operations within a parenthesis are done before addition and subtraction, per the [order of operations](http://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-pemdas.html).

Comment: It depends on what result you're looking for.  I'd guess the SQL one is correct.